# Replace CR and LF in variable

Tags: powershell

I have a bunch of text files in which I try to find and count the occurance of a two char string.

When found, I have the value in a variable, and I add that value to an array.

My problem is that the value in my variable contains CR and LF which I can't remove.

I load my data like this:

```
$arrayToSearch = Get-Content $myFile | Select-String -Pattern $mySearchString

foreach($lineToProcess in $arrayToSearch)
{
  $myVar = ($lineToProcess -split $leadingStringPattern) -split $trailingSringPattern

  #here I need $myVar to only contain AB and not any Cr and/or Lf
}
```

I have tried theese different variants:

```
$myVar = $myVar -replace '(?:\s|\r|\n)',''

$myVar = $myVar.replace("\n","")

$myVar = $myVar.name.substring(0,2)

$myVar = $myVar -split "\n"

$myVar = $myVar -split "`r`n"

$myVar = $myVar -replace "`t|`n|`r",""

$newLine = [environment]::NewLine
$myVar = $myVar -replace $newLine,""
```

None works. Any other suggestion?

What I get (CrLf=Carrige Return and Line Feed):

CrLf

ABCrLf

CrLf

What I want:

AB

Comment: What does the original `$myVar` contain and what do you want it to ultimately contain? The question matters because you don't need to clean up `CRLF` characters on strings that weren't correctly manipulated before that point. If you are using `Get-Content` to read files, consider using `Get-Content -Raw` to make sure you are dealing with raw strings rather than arrays. Typically `$myVar -replace '\r?\n'` works in most cases.

Comment: It should work.  Where does $myVar come from?

Comment: if you are loading a text file with `Get-Content` but without `-Raw` ... you will NOT have a string. you will have an _array of strings_. that means there will not be any newlines since the `G-C` call loads lines of text as bare text. so ... as others have asked ... where is your text coming from and how are you loading it into your $Var?

Comment: Try ```$myVar = $myVar -split "`n"```

Comment: Did you try `$myVar.Trim()`. Also, your code is weird.. You are getting something from a text file into `$arrayToSearch`, but next you loop through some other undefined variable called `$searchArray`. Show your **REAL** code and explain any variable that seems to come from nowhere.

Comment: Corrected code. Sorry for that. Have tried suggestions above. None work...